# How to use variable as key in YAML?\

Tags: docker, ansible

I want to use the index as the key for the docker node label generation using ansible.

I have tried the following code but the same doesn't replace the index value.

```
---

  - name: Assigning labels
    hosts: localhost
    connection: local
    gather_facts: no

    tasks:
    - name: Localhost label assignment
      docker_node:
        hostname: "{{ item }}"
        labels:
          "{{ idx }}": "true"
      with_items:
        - "{{ groups['target-machines'] }}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: idx
```

The docker node inspect looks something like this on successful completion of the playbook.

```
"Spec": {
            "Labels": {
                "{{ idx }}": "true",
            },
            "Role": "manager",
            "Availability": "active"
        },
```

However what I want to achieve is:

NODE:1

```
"Spec": {
            "Labels": {
                1: "true",
            },
            "Role": "manager",
            "Availability": "active"
        },
```

NODE:2

```
"Spec": {
            "Labels": {
                2: "true",
            },
            "Role": "manager",
            "Availability": "active"
        },
```

.
.
.
. and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expand the index. Correct syntax is (without *%* if you don't need it)

```
labels:
  "{{ idx }}": "true"
```

Comment: "Spec": {
            "Labels": {
                "{{ idx }}": "true"
            },
            "Role": "manager",
            "Availability": "active"
        }


This is what I get on doing node inspect. The index is not getting replaced.

Comment: Updating the question to include this step. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

in case you still need it, just have found this. use combine to make up dict and pass it to labels field.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62010666/ansible-how-to-set-docker-container-labels-with-dynamic-key-names)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).