# How would I configure a dictionary which requires variables in a loop?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a docker_container which I want to deploy for multiple users and name traefik routes after the users. But i'm confused on how I can achieve this.

Here is what I have:

```
- name: Run syncthing
  docker_container:
    name: "{{ item.name }}-syncthing"
    image: "lscr.io/linuxserver/syncthing"
    state: started
    restart_policy: "always"
    env:
      PUID: "1000"
      PGID: "1000"
    volumes:
      - "{{ item.data_dir }}:/data"
... other volumes
    labels:
      traefik.enable: true
      "traefik.http.routers.{{ item.name }}-syncthing.entrypoints": websecure
      "traefik.http.routers.{{ item.name }}-syncthing.rule": Host(`{{ item.name }}.{{ fqdn_real }}`)
      "traefik.http.routers.{{ item.name }}-syncthing.tls": true
      "traefik.http.routers.{{ item.name }}-syncthing.tls.certresolver": le 
      "traefik.http.routers.{{ item.name }}-syncthing.service": "{{ item.name }}-syncthing"
      "traefik.http.routers.{{ item.name }}-syncthing.middlewares": "{{ item.name }}-basicauth"
      "traefik.http.services.{{ item.name }}-syncthing.loadbalancer.server.port": 8080
      "traefik.http.middlewares.{{ item.name }}-syncthing-basicauth.basicauth.users": "{{ item.auth }}"
  with_items: "{{ syncthing_containers_info }}"
```

And a `syncthing_config_info` like this:

```
syncthing_containers_info:
  - { name: "c1", data_dir: "/mnt/data/c1/data", auth: "..." }
  - { name: "c2", data_dir: "/mnt/data/c2/data", auth: "..." }
  - { name: "c3", data_dir: "/mnt/data/c3/data", auth: "..." }
```

That snippet doesn't work because ansible doesn't like the syntax so I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62010666/ansible-how-to-set-docker-container-labels-with-dynamic-key-names) with a `with_nested` but I faced a similar problem there with the nested loop issue while trying to `set_fact` as in the example since the set of labels depends on `syncthing_containers_info`. Is there a better way for me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need the `labels:` to be an actual `dict` since yaml keys are not subject to jinja2 interpolation

```yaml
    labels: >-
      {%- set key_prefix = "traefik.http.routers." ~ item.name ~"-syncthing" -%}
      {{ {
      "traefik.enable": True,
      key_prefix ~ ".entrypoints": "websecure",
      key_prefix ~ ".rule": "Host(`" ~ item.name ~"."~ fqdn_real ~"`)",
      key_prefix ~ ".tls": True,
      key_prefix ~ ".tls.certresolver": "le",
      key_prefix ~ ".service": item.name ~ "-syncthing",
      key_prefix ~ ".middlewares": item.name ~ "-basicauth",
      "traefik.http.services." ~ item.name ~ "-syncthing.loadbalancer.server.port": 8080,
      "traefik.http.middlewares." ~ item.name ~"-syncthing-basicauth.basicauth.users": item.auth,
      } }}
```

*(be aware I didn't test that, just eyeballed it from your question, but that's the general idea)*

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! I just had to update the `True` to `"true"` and it just worked. Can you tell me what this syntax is called or point me to docs on it?

Comment: ah, yes, because labels are string-string pairs; sorry about that! that is [jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/), the templating/scripting language shipped with ansible. it's _mostly_ python syntax, but there are for sure some weird differences that make for a lot of SO questions :-(